# Autofill a textfield with url from another website through bookmarklet

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I need a bit of clue here.  What I want to do is to allow user to submit a url to my website through a bookmarklet.  So when they click on the bookmarklet, the textfield with id (`field_url`) will be autofilled with the url on the page they are on. I looked around and found that I need to use this piece of code for the bookmarklet.

```
javascript:location.href="http://mywebsite.com/geturl.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(location.href);
```

My question: what should I put in `geturl.php` in order to autofill the textfield?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the URL through a [`GET` parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), so normally you'd just have to [`echo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) it in your php page:

```
<input type="text" id="field_url" value="<?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>" />
```

The shorthand method is `<?=$_GET['url']?>`, but I prefer to stay away from PHP shorthands.